# AWS disk space increase lead to incorrect volume size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have increased disk space from AWS console from 50Gb to 128 GB, however the ec2 was down at that time. During the volume optimisation process I have started ec2 instance. I can see that volume was already grown:-

```
>lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
loop1         7:1    0 93.9M  1 loop /snap/core/9066
loop2         7:2    0   97M  1 loop /snap/core/9289
nvme0n1     259:0    0  128G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  128G  0 part /
```

While output for df -h is as below

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            125G     0  125G   0% /dev
tmpfs            25G  844K   25G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  125G   23G  102G  18% /
tmpfs           125G     0  125G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           125G     0  125G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop1       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
tmpfs            25G     0   25G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Couple of things -

1. / is 125 GB instead of 128 GB
2. udev automatically become 125 GB

Comment: Udev is 50% of Ram Size

Comment: / is always some part less than df -h

Answer (score 0):

This is as per AWS feature. Udev -> represent Ram, Hard disk is some part less than allocated.